# WebSite Started to throw error : System resource exceeded. (Access DB)

Tags: database, ms-access, iis

I have a webpage that is giving me this error on a couple of pages

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers error '8007000e'

[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] System resource exceeded. 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have been trying to find a solution but still haven't had any luck.
This web page was working fine for the past week, even months.

Can someone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We see this periodically on our shared hosting platform. Here is some advice and guidance we provide our users:

1. Close your database connections after you use them
2. Compact your access database, see the following article on ASPFAQ: [Can I compact / repair an Access database from ASP code?](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/can-i-compact/repair-an-access-database-from-asp-code.html)
3. Switch from ODBC to OLEDB (you'll need to use a DSN'less connection string). We find ODBC to be the root cause of many Access database problems. i.e. [`Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;`](http://www.connectionstrings.com/access)
4. Ensure you're using a later version of the Access database format. Anything pre-Access 2000 is prone to breaking under hosting conditions.
5. `SELECT` less data from your tables. i.e. only query for what you need and get rid of those `SELECT * FROM`'s, preferring to just select the columns you need
6. If your database is any bigger than 100Mb after compacting then consider upgrading to MS SQL or porting to MySQL. We find that Access databases become troublesome when they exceed 100Mb on shared hosting.
7. If you're seeing more than 10-15 concurrent connections to your website then it's time to consider upgrading to MS SQL or MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps have database connections that are not being closed properly and are staying open?

Comment: not that i can see... im going threw the code now...
anymore suguestion

Answer (score 0):

There is key in registry to change:

"MaxLocksPerFile"

It can be in two branches:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Jet 4.0]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Jet 3.x]

Current value is 9500. Set 119500 instead.